# VS2012 and InstallShield 2014 Premier Issue

Tags: visual-studio-2012, installshield, installshield-le, installshield-2014

I've been using VS2012 with `InstallShield2014LE` on our existing projects.We finally purchased the installed 2014 premier and when I open/load an existing solution that has a 2014LE setup project alongside the main project, I get the following error, when I add a 2014 Basic MSI project:

> The system cannot open the device or file specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007006e)

I can create the project using the standalone InstallShield app.

Even I can create new solutions in Visual Studio 2012 and then add the basic msi to the it. That works just perfectly, but when I try to load the .ISM file in VS2012 or add a basic msi, I get the above error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Yuo have to manually re-enable integration between InstallShield and Visual Studio.

The problem, perhaps, derived from previous installation of InstallShield LE.
New instalation of purchased InstallShield has not registered correctly the required dll... so... you have to do it manually:

1. Open DOS prompt in **ADMINISTRATIVE MODE** (Very Important)
2. Goto [InstallShield 2014 Installation Folder]/System
3. Type "**regsvr32 IsDevEdt.dll**" to register DLL
4. Type "**regsvr32 IsDevPkg.dll**" to register DLL
5. Type "**regsvr32 IsDevWiz.dll**" to register DLL
6. Locate devenv.exe corresponding to the version of Visual Studio.NET
   2012 (perhaps C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio
   11\Common7\IDE)
7. Type "**devenv.exe /setup**" to run the integration setup

Now... everything should work.